# Update using Entity Framework - Best Approach EF5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I was searching for a better approach when a updating the DB using Entity FrameWork 5.

Similar to this post  [Better way to update a record using Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616276/better-way-to-update-a-record-using-entity-framework)

If i have more number of columns then this is not better?

Apart from Auto mapper is there any other updates now?

I was going through other post which implemented the below approach

```
context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(updated)
```

Is this the better one ?

Any New ideas are most welcome. May be I am outdated :)

Comment: AutoMapper or ValueInjecter should work just fine in such scenarios and they're both really easy to use...

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek how about using ontext.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues ?  Is there any impact ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following URi : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

You work with a generic repository, so you can use it to acces all of your tables inside your database with a single class. Just follow the tutorial, it is pretty straight forward.